# Is it possible to empirically discriminate distributions of the probability of a binary outcome?

Tags: probability, distributions, philosophical

I am interested in systems with an observable binary outcome (e.g. Success, Failure). The individual cases are usually modelled (e.g. using logistic regression) as having an estimated probability of success.

This probability of success could be viewed as just a side effect of observational ignorance:

- Each case is predetermined as a Success or Failure. We just don't
  know until we look, and the set of covariates doesn't allow
  partitioning the cases into exclusively S or F cases, so every group
  of cases we can identify by the covariates has a mixture of S and F.

Or the probability of success could be viewed as a real but unobservable property of each case:

- Cases are not predetermined to be S or F, rather that status is
  determined by some outcome process such that when we get around to
  observing it, each case will be S or F. Each case has an unobservable
  probability of Success that determines the probability that the
  observed outcome is S and we have no access to any better
  information.

If we take the latter interpretation, it makes sense to talk about the distribution of the probability of S over cases. Given some group of cases with a known group probability of S it seems to me that there are an infinite number of distributions of case-level P(S) that would yield the same group-level P(S), i.e. all distributions with the same expectation of P(S). This would range from all cases having identically the same P(S) through to each case having P(S) either 1 or 0, with the group-level P(S) determined by the fraction of cases having case-level P(S) = 1.

So the question is: **Assuming each case has it's own fixed probability of Success and only the outcomes can be observed, is it possible to empirically discriminate between different distributions of probability of Success over cases?** I strongly suspect the answer is 'No'.

If the distributions can't be empirically discriminated, is it possible to relax some aspect of the above assumptions (e.g. by allowing partial observability of the process that translates the unobservable probability of Success into the observable outcome) so that the distributions of probability of Success are empirically discriminable? That is: **What would you have to do to make it possible to empirically discriminate between different distributions of probability of Success over cases?**

Thanks

Ross

Comment: Can you give us some simple example? E.g. "we have two urns filled with black and white balls..."

Comment: I give an 'urns' example in the comments to Dalton Hance's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Assuming each case has it's own fixed probability of Success and only the outcomes can be observed, is it possible to empirically discriminate between different distributions of probability of Success over cases?"

If each case has it's own fixed probability of success then that probability is indistinguishable from the outcome. That is $P(X_i = 1)$ must be either 1 or 0 because there is no chance for it to be otherwise - because by your definition each $S_i$ is unique and paired directly with an $X_i$. So, yes it is possible to model some distribution over $\bf{S}$, but all you've done is add another layer of meaningless abstraction. Instead of your data being Bernoulli distributed, your parameters are Bernoulli distributed, and we can described the parameters of some hyper-distribution with co-variates, probably with logistic regression. At a certain point, you need some concept of replication to be able to resolve a statistic. And here all a statistic means is some shorthand summary of data or in your abstract case of parameters. Otherwise, all you have is one long series of unique events with no more sufficient or compact way to describe them then to simply observe them.

Comment: "If each case has it's own fixed probability of success then that probability is indistinguishable from the outcome. That is $P(X_{i}=1)$ must be either 1 or 0" I don't follow you. Consider where each case corresponds to an urn containing some fixed number of white and black balls and observing a case corresponds to drawing one ball from the urn. That system is physically implementable, and it makes sense to say that each urn has a probability of drawing black that is not constrained to 0 or 1. I don't see any way to empirically determine those probabilities given 1 draw per urn. (continued)

Comment: Given 1 draw per urn and no covariates related to per urn probability I don't see any way to know the per urn probability, which I think is the point of @Dalton's "all you've done is add another layer of meaningless abstraction". It may correspond to reality, but you can't demonstrate it and it doesn't help you achieve anything. Even if we were magically granted some new predictive covariates I think we would end up the same place. It now appears to me that having only one observation per urn is the real bottleneck. (continued)

Comment: If we could get multiple observations per urn of the outcome or possibly time-varying predictors it might make sense to talk of the distribution of probabilities across urns.

Comment: We could get pretty metaphysical here, but I think the point is that in order to say something about parameter you need to view it as more durable than you data. Pardon if I run your magical urn example out: what you are positing is thatwe image ourselves in a room with a potentially infinite number of urns. We know nothing about the contents of the urns, except that there are some number of black balls and some number of white balls. (The owners of the magical room have assured us no urn will spout green balls, or blue balls, or Jerry Lee Lewis' great balls of fire.) [cont.]

Comment: In the magical urn room, we can select anyone of these urns and draw one ball. Immediately after we draw the ball and observe its color, the urn and its contents evaporate. What can we say about that urn? Nothing, except that we observed a black or white ball. The rules of the room are such that we can't peek at the urn or even count how many balls are in it without observing their color. So an urn that contains only one ball is identical to an urn that contains infinite balls.

Comment: [Jack Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._J._Good) noted that in the Middle Ages the appearance of the dark side of the moon and the number of angels that could dance on the head of a pin were equally metaphysical questions, but not in the 20th century. If we want to use formal tools in science we have to map the system of interest to a formal framework and scientists don't mind using idealisations like point masses and infinitely distant light sources. [cont.]

Comment: Also because the physical system and the conceptual framework are not the same thing it is perfectly possible the impossible to happen, like a green ball drawn from the putatively black and white urn or an unexpected particle being observed at the LHC. So dropping the "magic" from the urn room, I am confident that I can construct a finite one that behaves as expected - so that's an internally consistent and reasonable conceptual framework. Does it help me, empirically? I agree with you - not if we have the "only 1 observation per urn" constraint - so Q1 is answered. [cont.]

Comment: "in order to say something about parameter you need to view it as more durable than you data" <- That's a nice way of putting it. So coming to Q2, in order for the conceptual framework (i.e. having a per-urn probability) to be useful we need to relax the one-observation per urn constraint so that the parameter is more durable than the individual observations (e.g. by allowing multiple observations per urn).

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you would have to do in order to empirically discriminate between the $P(S_{i})$ is find some characteristic which varies among the i's that correlates with higher or lower $P(S_i)$.

For example, take wine making.  It takes a long time to make wine, and it is not immediately obvious through any known chemical testing to determine if a particular year/vintage will be "good."  However, in the book "Supercrunchers" a formula is described (see review at http://www.fool.com/investing/small-cap/2007/10/31/foolish-book-review-super-crunchers.aspx), which converts temperature and rainfall into a quality rating.  Of course there are many other hidden variables, and it does not guarantee an exact level of quality.  However, I hope that this example shows how using salient features of a process can help one forecast the end result of that process.

Comment: "in order to empirically discriminate between the $P(S_{i})$ ... find some characteristic which varies among the i's that correlates with higher or lower $P(S_{i})$"

I get that adding predictors allows finer discrimination of the probabilities. My 1st question is: Assuming all possible predictors have been used, the values of the predictors partition the cases, and assign a group probability to each cell of the partition; is it possible to empirically discriminate between different distributions of case probabilities that yield the same group probability?